# SwiftUI NavigationLink behave unexpectedly inside a TabView when returning from the main screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There is a bug in SwiftUI where NavigationLink behaves unexpectedly inside a TabView.
The NavigationLink inside a TabView is not preserved the View when returning from the main screen. The bug can be reproduced in iOS 16.1 on the iPhone 14 Pro simulator using Xcode 14.1.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq1OP.gif)

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ExempleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink() {
                Text("The page is retained after returing from the main screen.")
            } label: {
                Text("This works")
            }
            
            TabView() {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink() {
                        Text("The page doesn't stay after returing from the main screen.")
                    } label: {
                        Text("This doesn't work")
                    }
                }
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "bookmark")
                    }
                    .tag(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `NavigationLink` inside the `TabView` should act like the normal one. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Can you target iOS 16? Looks like this bug doesn't happen with `NavigationStack` instead of `NavigationView`. Going to see if I can figure this out anyway but that'd fix it.

Comment: I would say that adding a navigation link in a tabview which is not the full screen is not good : you can see that the link in tab view does not preserve the tab as it does if tab view is the main view.

Comment: @AndrewCarter thanks for the comment! Using `NavigationStack` instead of `NavigationView` works like a charm.

Comment: Tab view should always be at the very top of the hierarchy. This is by Apple design you will have many navigation bug if you have the stack at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the @AndrewCarter . I fixed the problem by replacing `NavigationView` with `NavigationStack`.

Warning: `NavigationStack` only available in iOS16 and newer.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because you use a TabView inside of a NavigationView. This causes the problems that you have. I would suggest to let the tabview fill the whole page and let the NavigationView be part of it.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ExempleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                NavigationView {
                    NavigationLink() {
                        Text("The page is retained after returing from the main screen.")
                    } label: {
                        Text("This works")
                    }
                    
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink() {
                            Text("The page doesn't stay after returing from the main screen.")
                        } label: {
                            Text("This doesn't work")
                        }
                    }.tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "bookmark")
                    }.tag(0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! but I ran your code and the `VStack` doesn't show up at all.